# Multiple nonlinear regression model with p>n

Tags: r, multiple-regression, regularization, nonlinear-regression, polynomial

I'd like to perform a **nonlinear** regression on a dataset that has more predictors than observations ($p$ =100, $n$=50), and predictors can also be multicollinear; i.e. the data is similar to a gene expression data set, but smaller. My response variable and all my predictors are numerics. Basically, I want to do something similar to an **elastic net** regression (combining $L1$ & $L2$ penalty), including variable selection, but looking for nonlinear relationships instead of linear ones. "Worst" case a quadratic fit would also be ok, as I expect most predictors will have an "optimum" (curvilinear).

What I have found by googling is that a GAM model with smoothing function + L1 penalty could be a solution, however I have not yet found a *R* package that can do this and handle the $p>n$ situation.

Can someone tell me if there is a simple solution which I just don't see, or, if not, point me in the right direction?

Comment: Neural networks allow for regularization and are nonlinear if you use a nonlinear activation function.

Comment: Thank you @Dave